# What is the story behind Bitcoinica?

Tags: services, websites, history, bitcoinica

[Bitcoinica](https://www.bitcoinica.com) was a very popular service when it was operating. What is the story behind it - when was it started, what did it offer, and what hurdles did it face?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3629/what-is-the-story-behind-the-linode-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a good summary: http://arstechnica.com/uncategorized/2012/05/bitcoins-worth-87000-plundered/

Even more summarised thanks to [freesummarizer.com](http://freesummarizer.com):

> More than $87,000 worth of the virtual currency known as Bitcoin was
>   stolen after online bandits penetrated servers belonging to
>   Bitcoinica, prompting its operators to temporarily shutter the trading
>   platform to contain the damage.
>
> Friday's theft came after hackers accessed Bitcoinica's production
>   servers and depleted its online wallet of 18,547 BTC, as individual
>   Bitcoin units are called, company officials said in a blog post
>   published on Friday.
>
> In early March, a security lapse at cloud services provider Linode
>   allowed hackers to make off with about $210,000 worth of bitcoin after
>   they gained unauthorized access to bitcoin wallets stored by
>   Bitcoinica and seven other customers.
>
> Strong cryptographic controls ensure that once bitcoins are spent they
>   can't be taken back, although a recently published research paper
>   reports limitations that allow the same bitcoins to be double spent in
>   certain cases (which Bitcoin developers say they've long warned users
>   to avoid).
>
> The March heist that hit Bitcoinica also affected several other
>   trading platforms that have also lamented the necessity of storing
>   large amounts of the currency in liquid form in "hot wallets" to
>   automatically cover payout requests made by customers.

Comment: Please summarize articles in the event that they get taken down.